# Message queue with consumer-based loading balancing

Tags: load-balancing, message-queue

Reading the documentation of common message queueing systems (e.g. RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ) it seems that load balancing is always done by the queueing system (round-robin) or by the producer using several queues or attributes on messages. However in our application nobody, not even the consumers, knows how long it will take to process a message. It can be between several milliseconds to hours (it's basically computing an arbitrary function f on an arbitrary input x). Therefore load balancing should be performed by the consumers in that they only accept messages if their "load" is below a threshold (load can be number of executing jobs, CPU load, etc.). Ideally the producer puts a message in the queue, the message is "offered" to all consumers, but only exactly one consumer accepts and processes the message. It may even happen that no consumer accepts it in the first round and it stays in the queue until one consumer has free resources.
So may question is: is this somehow possible with any of the common message queueing system or are we looking in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 4):

This is achievable without any real additional work just due to the nature of these systems. In RabbitMQ, you can set a [prefetch size](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html), which specifies the number of jobs to fetch ahead of time. You'd set this to 0, so that each consumer may only have one job at a time. You want to use this in combination with message acknowledgements, so that a consumer has to ack a message before it'll be offered another one.

All the idle consumers will line up waiting for jobs, and the MQ will spool off jobs to them in FIFO order. Once they finish processing their job, they ack it and the MQ gives them the next job in the queue. If no consumers are idle and ready for a job, then the message sits in the queue until a consumer becomes available.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds about perfect. I will give it a try.